# How To Vertically Center Text Over Responsive Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-video

For some reason this is giving me heck and can't find a solid answer.

I have a video playing in the background that goes to full-width and is responsive to the screen size. I have a title/text over the video. But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to vertically center this text to the video in a responsive way! Thanks for any help!

#### Codepen:

http://codepen.io/149203/pen/VagPxe

#### html:

```
<body>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="video-container">
      <video preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" volume="0">
            <source src="https://originate-v3-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/sites/53854785dc60d94b96000002/pages/53854785dc60d94b96000004/files/Originate_B_W_Small6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div> <!-- video-container -->
    <h3>Centered Title</h3>
    <h6>This should be vertically and horizontally centered</h6>
  </div> <!-- header-container -->
</body>
```

#### css:

```
.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
}

.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%;
}

h3,
h6 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

#### pulling in this css:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found and forked this CodePen. This is the best solution I found. (Uses Bootstrap.)

http://codepen.io/149203/pen/JXxbEL

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 vert-center-container">
    <video autoplay loop style="width:100%" class="img-responsive">
      <source src="https://originate-v3-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/sites/53854785dc60d94b96000002/pages/53854785dc60d94b96000004/files/Originate_B_W_Small6.mp4" />
    </video>
    <div class="vert-center-text">
      <h1>Caption Text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.vert-center-text {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 40%; 
   left: 0;
   text-align: center; 
   width: 100%; 
}

.vert-center-text h1 { 
    color: white;
}

.vert-center-container {
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Display wrapper to `display: table`, change child element to `display: table-cell`, `vertiacl-align: middle.`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWwLPP

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help! Unfortunately your codepen **isn't really centered** (it's a little low on my screen) AND it stays in the same place when the window changes size (i.e. **it's not responsive like the question is asking for**), giving the effect that the text moves to the bottom of the video and then goes offscreen if the user reduces their screen size.

Would love a solution where the text is vertically centered over the video in a responsive way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

simulate the  the header container as table and h3,h6 as table-cell with `vertical-align:middle`

```css
.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  display:table;
}

.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

}

video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -100;
  width: 100%;
}

h3,
h6 {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="video-container">
      <video preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" volume="0">
            <source src="https://originate-v3-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/sites/53854785dc60d94b96000002/pages/53854785dc60d94b96000004/files/Originate_B_W_Small6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <!-- video-container -->
    <h3>Centered Title</h3>
    <h6>This should be vertically and horizontally centered</h6>
  </div>
  <!-- header-container -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to help! But **this does not make the centered text responsive.** If I change the window size, and the video reduces size, your text **stays in the same place** and eventually **slides off the bottom of the video.**

I ran your snippet in full page to test.

Would love a solution where the text is vertically centered over the video in a responsive way as I ask in the question. Thanks again!

Comment: For a dynamic solution you have to recheck and update the height of h3 and h6 according to their parents using jquery on window resize.